# How to run a function while ignoring several lines in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a file that looks like this:

> a
>   b
>   str1
>   c
>   d
>   str2
>   e
>   f

Now I want to run a re.sub() function that applies to lines in this file except lines between "str1" and "str2" (i.e. only apply to line "a", "b", "e" and "f"). How should I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Implement a FSM.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams a [Flying Spaghetti Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster)? /s

Answer (score 2):

```
between_strings = False

for line in lines:
    if line == 'str1':
        between_strings = True
    elif line == 'str2':
        between_strings = False
        continue
    if not between_strings:
        re.sub(line)
```

Here is how I would implement this. It would check each line, and when it finds str1, set between_strings to True. When it is True it would skip lines. Once it finds str2 it will begin reading lines again. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a loop within a loop to skip lines while iterating over a file

```
with open(infile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line == 'str1':
            for line in f:
                if line=='str2': break
        else:
            re.sub(line)
```